# get data attribute and append optimize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been fiddling around and with some code I found here I managed to get some working code although I wonder if it can be optimized further.

I have tried to comment the code so my thought process is shown. If anyone knows a better way to achieve to [**get the data-tid attribute and append the value to a span in that tablerow to a td**] I would love to hear it.

```html
<table>
            <tr data-tid="3"><td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td><td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td></tr>
            <tr data-tid="2"><td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td><td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td></tr>
            <tr data-tid="5"><td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td><td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td></tr>
            <tr data-tid="6"><td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td><td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td></tr>
        </table>
```

```js
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
            $j(document).ready(function() {

                topiclistview = $j('[data-tid]').length;                

                // check if data-tid exists
                if (topiclistview > 0) {
                    //set vars
                    var tids = $j('[data-tid]');
                    var tids_array = [];
                    //get the data attribute values and put them in an array
                    $j(tids).each(function(index, item) {
                        tids_array.push($j(item).data('tid'));                        
                    });
                    //run over all tr with the class .col_f_content and append the attribute value
                    $j('.col_f_content').each(function(index, item){
                        $j('<span>'+tids_array[index]+'</span>').appendTo($j(item));
                        //console.log('tr item'+tids_array[index]);
                        });

                    }

                

            });
```

Comment: Where is the `span`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/70j1oxa7/

Comment: What are your goals with this? Is this just for the sake of seeing where your code can be improved? Are you looking for performance or readability?

Comment: Required reading: http://learn.jquery.com/performance/

Comment: To be honest I would love code that is readable and performs well. Unreadable highperformance code I am not looking for though. But I'm eager to learn new things and the answers below thought me at least 2 new things :) Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance-wise? This is probably a good shot:

```js
// iterate over all elements having the data-tid attribute
$("[data-tid]").each(function() {
  // Create our span. No need for a jQuery wrapper.
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  // Set the span text. No need to involve jQuery's data() function
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.getAttribute("data-tid")));
  // Add the span to your second cell (col_f_content). This should be way faster
  // than creating a new jQuery object via class selector.
  this.cells[1].appendChild(span);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-tid="3">
    <td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td>
    <td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-tid="2">
    <td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td>
    <td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-tid="5">
    <td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td>
    <td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-tid="6">
    <td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td>
    <td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, depending upon your needs, you could achieve something similar with CSS only:

```css
tr[data-tid]:after {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: attr(data-tid);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-tid="3">
    <td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td>
    <td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-tid="2">
    <td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td>
    <td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-tid="5">
    <td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td>
    <td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-tid="6">
    <td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td>
    <td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Canon, that looks very clean. May I assume this works faster due to not using any (or almost no) jquery functions?

Comment: You should be able to get more performance of you eliminate jQuery, but you're already using it for selection. How much performance do you *need*?

Comment: Thanks Canon ill have a look into caching jquery objects. I'm no javascript prodigy, so I heavily rely on jquery, but i promise to improve :D

Comment: @canon I agree with you, I was responding to the OP, not commenting on your answer.

Comment: Thx for the additional css alternative. I'm afraid I cant rely on the content property.

Comment: @canon it's greatly appreciated, the more info the better :) Learned a lot this day ty.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use intermediate arrays, and you can store the set of elements the first time you select them (when you test if there *are* any elements with `[data-tid]`).

It should be more performant to select based on a class, so if it's possible to add a class a class to the `data-tid` element html, we could use that for our selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    // We want to work with these elems
    var topiclist = $('[data-tid]');

    if (topiclist.length > 0) {
        // Just get the data, make a new elem and append it
        // All in 1 pass
        topiclist.each(function(_, el) {
            var $el = $(el);
            $el.append('<td>' + $el.data('tid') + '</td>');
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr data-tid="3"><td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td><td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td></tr>
    <tr data-tid="2"><td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td><td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td></tr>
    <tr data-tid="5"><td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td><td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td></tr>
    <tr data-tid="6"><td class="col_f_icon">aaa</td><td class="col_f_content">fdsfdsf</td></tr>
</table>
```

Also note, I'm appending a `<td>` with your contents to the `<tr>`, which is the element you selected. [`<span>` is not a legal child of `<tr>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element). If you want to do something with a `<span>`, you'll need to wrap it in a `<td>` if it's in a table.

Comment: Ha Jon, thx for the headsup, I should alter the title of the topic slightly, the Span is actually included in <td> element and not directly in the tr due to the classname in the td.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
$('[data-tid]').each(function(){
  var value = $(this).data('tid');

  $('<span>' + value + '</span>')
            .appendTo($(this).find('.col_f_content'));
});
```

(PS: Untested)